# div adaptable to their content and with the same width?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have 3 box, each one with its own content. Each box have a `width: 20%` and a `min-width: fit-content`. So, if I have a content that exceeds 20%, the box will adapt. However all box must have the same width. Which means that if a content in a box exceeds 20%, each other box must have the same size. [edit 2] More over, the content's layout mustn't be changed, it must be inline. [end edit 2]

I know that I can to this in JavaScript, but I want an optimized code, so I avoid using it. So how can I do this in pure CSS (Sass including), knowing that I know the content and that I use `em` unit.

I thought to calculate before the rendered (during the development) what will be the size of my text. But I don't know how do it...

But maybe someone knows a CSS Trick?

(each concerned `div` is in a flex parent)

#### Edit 1 (add code):

```
    &.experience {
                overflow-x: scroll;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;

                div.project {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    height: 75%;
                    width: 20%;
                    min-width: fit-content;
                    margin: 1em;
                    padding: 1em;
                    border-radius: 1.5em;
                    transition: .3s;
                    color: $color2;

                    div.project__image {
                        flex-grow: 1;
                        margin: 1em 0;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: center;
                        background-size: 75% auto;
                    }

                    &.lorem {
                        background-image: linear-gradient(165deg, #bae4b5, #96d68f);

                        div.project__image {
                            background-size: auto 75%;
                        }
                    }

                    &.lorem2 {
                        background-image: linear-gradient(165deg, #6a7ee0, #8595E6);

                        div.project__image {
                        }
                    }

                    &.lorem-impsum {
                        background-image: linear-gradient(165deg, #ffd147, #ffc105);

                        div.project__image {
                        }
                    }

                    &:hover {
                        transition: .3s;
                        transform: scale(1.05);

                        div.explanation {
                            opacity: 1;
                        }
                    }

                    header {
                        h3 {
                            margin: 0;
                            font-size: 1.5em;
                            font-weight: 700;

                            span {
                                font-size: 0.6em;
                                font-weight: 400;
                            }
                        }

                        p {
                            font-size: 0.8em;
                            font-weight: 200;
                        }
                    }

                    a.project__github-btn {
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        justify-content: flex-end;
                        color: $color2;

                        div {
                            height: 1em;
                            width: 1em;
                            margin-right: 0.3em;
                            @include svg-color("../res/github.svg", $color2);
                        }

                        p {
                            margin: 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

```html
        <section class="experience" id="experience">
           <div class="project lorem-impsum">
                <header>
                    <p>Internship</p>
                    <p>GLOBAL</p>
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum <span>- December 2018</span></h3>
                </header>
                <div class="project__image"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="project lorem">
                <header>
                    <p>Internship</p>
                    <p>MARKETING</p>
                    <h3>Lorem <span>- June 2019</span></h3>
                </header>
                <div class="project__image"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="project lorem2">
                <header>
                    <p>Project</p>
                    <p>HTML - CSS - JS - VUEJS</p>
                    <h3>Lorem <span>- March 2020</span></h3>
                </header>
                <div class="project__image"></div>
                <a href="#" class="project__github-btn">
                    <div></div>
                    <p>Voir sur GitHub</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: possible example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjYqRKN

Comment: I just edited and added the code

Comment: I forgot to say that the content must be inline, it mustn't have a line break

Comment: okay, remove max-width from the children in the pen example, it should basicly be what you look for :)